# Java Console Calculator with one line operations

Tags: java, console

I want to write a command line calculator but I want the scanner to handle an operation in only one line and not by many steps. e.g.:

mul 4 5

instead of

First number: 4  Second number: 5  Operation?(choose between...): mul

mul 4 5 should be possible to be written in one line without running more than one scanner, so mul [enter] 4 [enter] 5 [enter] isn't allowed. So the scanner has to control if the first part is a string and the other 2 parts are int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one line String then use split method to get the three value:

```
 System.out.println("Plase add your your operation : ");
 Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); 
 String input = myObj.nextLine();
 
 String[] array = new String[3];
 array = input.split("\s");
 String method = array[0];
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
```

Comment: I have to use java 11 and \s isn't supported. What else can i use?

Comment: what is the issue that you have, it is a regex so it is not related to java version.

Comment: yes it's a regex and not related to java 11

Comment: on docs.oracle it says for java 11 its \S but it says illegal escape character in string literal

Comment: no that is not correct this is different regex, as the regex is case sensitive. try \\s

Comment: yes \s to match a whitespace character that we need, but \S is to get any non space character which will not help in our case

Comment: Ok thx. How can I write everything in the same line as "Please add ur operation". So like this Please add ur operation mul 4 5 instead of Please add ur operation and then the entry in the next line | edit print instead of println

Comment: System.out.print("Plase add your your operation : "); change the first line using this. so I replaced the println to print

Comment: Hey I have one more question if u don't mind. How can I make the program accept the input `connect Xabc` ? connect is a string that doesn't change and Xabc is an int (the X) and a string (abc) that doesn't change. connect X abc is not allowed and Xabc is both an int and a string so how can I make the program recognize it because I can't enter an int+string in my array.

Comment: @xiaofeng Hi Can you please open new question with these details, I can check it for sure.